# How to split Bootstrap column in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap page with a top toolbar and two columns. On the left column I put the menu and a small block of text ( that maybe i will split in two). On the right column I have a big space where I show items (divs with imgs) based on what I select on the menu.

The design works well on computers, but when I open on mobile I'd like to move the bloc of text of the left column at the end of the mobile-page.

[image: layout]

The Top layout shows how it looks on a PC. The bottom left is what I would like to be able to do. The bottom right is another version of what I would like to do.

Right now I can only have the big textbox right after the menu when in mobile mode.

My code is like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" id="menu">..
<div id="text"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
<div class="container">
 ...items
</div>
</div> <!-- row..useless probably -->
```

How should I split the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One Textbox

Place the blocks in the order, which is necessary for the mobile screen. Then make `menu` right-floating on the wide screen.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#menu    { background: #cf9; height:  50px; }
#toolbar { background: #f9c; height:  50px; }
.items   { background: #9cf; height: 250px; }
.textbox { background: #fc9; height: 200px; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .items  {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="toolbar">Toolbar</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"  id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 items">Items</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 textbox">Textbox</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Two Textboxes

Wrap `menu` and `textbox 1` into an additional block. Then the problem will be similar to the previous one.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#menu    { background: #cf9; height:  50px; }
#toolbar { background: #f9c; height:  50px; }
.items   { background: #9cf; height: 250px; }
.textbox { background: #fc9; height: 100px; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .items  {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="toolbar">Toolbar</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="menu">Menu</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 textbox">Textbox 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 items">Items</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 textbox">Textbox 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, since in PC (wide) mode I see the textbox 2 correctly starting under the menu, but only after Items is finished. It might be all the DIVs I've enbedded in them. items are div (masonry) and on the menu there are divs.

Comment: @mobinoob Please give me a link to your page. Also you can add your new code at the end of your question.

Comment: here is an example with a random image from ebay. you should repeat that image a dozen or so times to see the effect. https://jsbin.com/cekezezoku/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @mobinoob My solution suggests that the height of the items block is greater than the height of the menu and the first text block together. Otherwise the second text block shifts to the right. I was guided by the scheme in your issue. If you need another layout, you can clarify your question or create a new one.

Comment: my bad. I forgot to mention that the items have to be copied several times. at least 10-15. So yes, the height is greater.  https://jsbin.com/burehacoze/edit?html,css

Comment: Still textbox 2 is below the height of the items

Comment: @mobinoob You need to add this CSS: `@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .items  {
    float: right !important;
  }
}`. Check: the result: https://jsbin.com/mafuvi/edit?output

Comment: as a side note, i noticed on mobile i can still scroll to the right. I'm investigating it now. it's surely unrelated to the previous issue i had. thanks.

Comment: @mobinoob You have to scroll because your `.footerbox1` class has the `width: 728px;` property.