# Bootstrap 5 split column on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have almost the same question as this guy [How to split Bootstrap column in mobile mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201005/how-to-split-bootstrap-column-in-mobile-mode) but I'm using Bootstrap 5 and the solution there with `float: right` is no longer working due to flexbox.

I have two columns on desktop and I want the first column insert in the middle of the second one on mobile. See my Excel artwork, I can't find any solution. Can any one help me please.

[image]

I've tried something like this, but I can't figure out how to put the "controls" under the "txt" content

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">text</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-0">img</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">controls</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your code so people can help

Comment: @mmh4all I've added my guess, but I don't think this will help anyone because it's probably wrong guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, friend of my helped me and coded it. For anyone having the same question, here's solution using CSS3 grid.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "txt"
    "img"
    "controls"
}

.container__img {
  grid-area: img;
}

.container__txt {
  grid-area: txt;
}

.container__controls {
  grid-area: controls;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "img txt"
      "img controls";
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/stepanhalir/pen/rNrJrvg

Answer (score 0):

## Note:

The image you provided can never be resulted from the code you added for
desktop, but as far as I understand your question. This might be helpful. (without using order)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-light">Image</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="bg-warning">text</div>
        <div class="bg-success">controls</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I added colors for simplicity.